# Load balancer error during Kubernetes 3 tier configuration

Tags: kubernetes

everyone
I'm asking this question because there was an error while making 3 tier with Kubernetes

```
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: petclinic-svc
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: petclinic-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: metallb-config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.56.240-192.168.56.250
```

I wrote the yaml file
If you do kubectl apply -f 000.yaml,

```
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/petclinic-deployment-5df754cc5c-nfj84   3/3     Running   0          7m12s

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        4d21h
service/petclinic-svc   LoadBalancer   10.102.197.181   <pending>     80:31925/TCP   7m12s

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/petclinic-deployment   1/1     1            1           7m12s

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/petclinic-deployment-5df754cc5c   1         1         1       7m12s
```

pending in load balancer
I want to solve this problem

Comment: You will need to add information about what the actual issue is that you're facing and how that manifests. Error messages and logs, can help the community to help you.

Comment: This often means that your cluster is not configured to run a controller to actually create a load balancer.  Doing that is specific to how and where your cluster is installed, and is not typically a programming problem.  The linked question has several examples, including for more developer-oriented tools like minikube.